# Object reference passing in raphael drag function

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am creating a module to graphically visualize workflows using raphael,which take data from a data base. For this i have created a class called "FlowEdit", and created move, up and dragger function according to raphael.

But in move function when i am trying to access connections list using object reference, than i am unable to reference it, it gives undefined error.

Code for the class is this:-

```
        //class definition
        function FlowView(list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.connections = [];
        this.r = Raphael("holder", 1400, 500);
        this.shapes = [];
        this.texts = [];
        this.y_center = 500 / 2;
        //box size
        this.r_width = 60;
        this.r_height = 40;
        // To define virtual regions
        this.x_offset = 50;
        this.y_offset = 40;
        this.x_start = 40;
        //this.color, this.tempS, this.tempT;
        //Define position in y direction
        this.top_count = [0];
        this.bottom_count = [0];
        //Initialize Top_count & Bottom_Count Arrays
        for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
            this.top_count.push(0);
            this.bottom_count.push(0);
        }
    }
    ;

    // Give starting points from list
    FlowView.prototype.start_point = function () {
        var start_list = [];
        for (var i in this.list) {
            if (this.list[i][1] == this.list[i][2][0]) {
                start_list.push(this.list[i][1]);
            }
        }
        return start_list;
    };

    //For Finding index of an element in list
    FlowView.prototype.index_of = function (curr_point) {
        for (var i in this.list) {
            if (this.list[i][1] == curr_point) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    };

    //add next function
    FlowView.prototype.add_next = function () {
        for (var i in this.list) {
            if (this.list[i][3][0] == "NULL") {
                //For all last nodes add same to their next
                this.list[i][3][0] = this.list[i][1];
            }
            if (this.list[i][3].length == 0) {
                //For all last nodes add same to their next
                this.list[i][3].push(this.list[i][1]);
            }
        }
    };

    //For given next of all nodes add previous to those nodes
    FlowView.prototype.add_previous = function () {
        for (var i in this.list) {
            for (var j in this.list[i][3]) {
                //For all next add current node to their previous list
                var curr_index = this.index_of(this.list[i][3][j]);
                if (this.list[curr_index][2].indexOf(this.list[i][1]) == -1 && (curr_index != i)) {
                    this.list[curr_index][2].push(this.list[i][1]);
                }
            }
        }
        //Add previous of all start node
        for (var i in this.list) {
            if (this.list[i][2].length == 0) {
                this.list[i][2].push(this.list[i][1]);
            }
        }
    };


    //Region update recursively
    FlowView.prototype.region_update = function (curr_index) {
        if (this.list[curr_index][1] != this.list[curr_index][3][0]) {
            for (var i in this.list[curr_index][3]) {
                var next_index = this.index_of(this.list[curr_index][3][i]);
                if (this.list[next_index][0] < this.list[curr_index][0] + 1) {
                    this.list[next_index][0] = this.list[curr_index][0] + 1;
                    this.region_update(next_index);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //Draw the workflow for given data structure
    FlowView.prototype.construct = function () {
        var open = this.start_point();
        var close = [];

        while (open.length != 0) {
            var curr_point = open.shift();
            var curr_index = this.index_of(curr_point);
            //document.write(curr_index);
            //draw box
            var curr_region = this.list[curr_index][0];
            //document.write(curr_region);
            var x_cord = parseInt(curr_region) * (this.x_offset + this.r_width) + this.x_start;
            //document.write(x_start);
            var y_cord = 0;

            if (this.top_count[curr_region] == 0 && this.bottom_count[curr_region] == 0) {
                y_cord = this.y_center - this.r_height / 2;
                this.top_count[curr_region] = 1;
                this.bottom_count[curr_region] = 1;
            }
            else if (this.top_count[curr_region] <= this.bottom_count[curr_region]) {
                y_cord = this.y_center - this.r_height / 2 - this.top_count[curr_region] * (this.y_offset + this.r_height);
                this.top_count[curr_region] = this.top_count[curr_region] + 1;
            }
            else {
                y_cord = this.y_center + this.r_height / 2 + this.bottom_count[curr_region] * (this.y_offset + this.r_height) - this.r_height;
                this.bottom_count[curr_region] = this.bottom_count[curr_region] + 1;
            }

            //drawing the box
            this.shapes[this.list[curr_index][1]] = this.r.rect(x_cord, y_cord, this.r_width, this.r_height, 10);
            this.texts[this.list[curr_index][1]] = this.r.text(x_cord + this.r_width / 2, y_cord + this.r_height / 2, this.list[curr_index][1]);
            // Adding next nodes to open list
            for (var i in this.list[curr_index][3]) {
                //If not in open than add to open
                if (this.list[curr_index][3][0] != this.list[curr_index][1]) {
                    if (open.indexOf(this.list[curr_index][3][i]) == -1 && close.indexOf(this.list[curr_index][3][i]) == -1) {
                        open.push(this.list[curr_index][3][i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Increasing region index for each next node
            this.region_update(curr_index);
            close.push(curr_point);
            //document.write(open.toString()+"</br>");
            //document.write(close.toString()+"</br>");
        }
        for (var j in this.list) {
            if (this.list[j][1] != this.list[j][3][0]) {
                for (var i in this.list[j][3]) {
                    //make link for each previous
                    if (close.indexOf(this.list[j][3][i]) != -1) {
                                 this.connections.push(this.r.connection(this.shapes[this.list[j][1]], this.shapes[this.list[j][3][i]], "bcd"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    FlowView.prototype.dragger = function () {
        // Original cords for main element
        this.ox = this.type == "ellipse" ? this.attr("cx") : this.attr("x");
        this.oy = this.type == "ellipse" ? this.attr("cy") : this.attr("y");
        if (this.type != "text") this.animate({"fill-opacity":.2}, 500);

        // Original co-ords for pair element
        this.pair.ox = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? this.pair.attr("cx") : this.pair.attr("x");
        this.pair.oy = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? this.pair.attr("cy") : this.pair.attr("y");
        if (this.pair.type != "text") this.pair.animate({"fill-opacity":.2}, 500);
    };

    FlowView.prototype.move = function (dx, dy) {
        // Move main element
        var att = this.type == "ellipse" ? {cx:this.ox + dx, cy:this.oy + dy} :
        {x:this.ox + dx, y:this.oy + dy};
        this.attr(att);
        // Move paired element
        att = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? {cx:this.pair.ox + dx, cy:this.pair.oy + dy} :
        {x:this.pair.ox + dx, y:this.pair.oy + dy};
        this.pair.attr(att);
        //document.write("adass");
        //document.write(x_offset);
        // Move connections
        for (var i = this.connections.length; i--;) {
             this.r.connection(this.connections[i]);
        }
        this.r.safari();
    };


    FlowView.prototype.up = function () {
        // Fade original element on mouse up
        if (this.type != "text") this.animate({"fill-opacity":0}, 500);

        // Fade paired element on mouse up
        if (this.pair.type != "text") this.pair.animate({"fill-opacity":0}, 500);
        // Move connections
    };


    FlowView.prototype.drag_initialize = function () {

        for (var i in this.shapes) {
            var color = Raphael.getColor();
            var tempS = this.shapes[i].attr({fill:color, stroke:color, "fill-opacity":0, "stroke-width":2, cursor:"move"});
            var tempT = this.texts[i].attr({fill:color, stroke:"none", "font-size":15, cursor:"move"});
            this.shapes[i].drag(this.move, this.dragger, this.up);
            this.texts[i].drag(this.move, this.dragger, this.up);

            // Associate the elements
            tempS.pair = tempT;
            tempT.pair = tempS;
        }
    };
```

Using above code i am able to draw graph & drag items,but when i drag items the connected path are not dragged along it.So where i am doing wrong. For making connection i used the same code given in raphael demos..

Comment: can you put a working example up on jsfiddle or somewhere similar? It helps us see what your doing.

Comment: [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/H3K7L/5/) This is the link for jsfiddle code. The problem is that I want the links between shapes to be dragged along with shapes. I change the links in move function accordingly when the shape is dragged. But i think the problem is that the context of the object in drag function is of the shape element and hence it is unable to understand this.connections which has FlowView object context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found the answer to the problem.
In the move function i return another function and while calling drag i give the object argument in move function hence the context of current object is passed. Now changed move function is:-

```
    FlowView.prototype.move = function (obj) {

        // Move main element
        return function(dx, dy){
            var att = this.type == "ellipse" ? {cx:this.ox + dx, cy:this.oy + dy} :
            {x:this.ox + dx, y:this.oy + dy};
            this.attr(att);
            // Move paired element
            att = this.pair.type == "ellipse" ? {cx:this.pair.ox + dx, cy:this.pair.oy + dy} :
            {x:this.pair.ox + dx, y:this.pair.oy + dy};
            this.pair.attr(att);
            // Move connections
            for (var i = obj.connections.length; i--;) {
                obj.r.connection(obj.connections[i]);
            }
            obj.r.safari();
        }
    };
```

And calling the drag with

```
    this.shapes[i].drag(this.move(this), this.dragger, this.up);
    this.texts[i].drag(this.move(this), this.dragger, this.up);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common annoyance and there is, fortunately, a very simple solution!

Problem: Raphael is using the functions you specify (this.move, this.dragger, and this.up) but it is NOT calling them in the context of your object.  So instead of referring to your object, the this variable is actually referring to window.  Decidedly not helpful.

Solution: use a function closure to bind in a reference to your object instance.  Update your drag_initialize function with this:

```
var self = this;
this.shapes[i].drag(function(){ self.move(); }, function() { self.dragger(); }, function() { self.up(); } );
this.texts[i].drag(function() { self.move(); }, function() { self.dragger(); }, function() { self.up(); } );
```